# What make scaled stage cost so much?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash

set the flash object's size to 100% on web page,and the stage scale to show_all

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

load the page on browser, change the browser window size, so the flash size also change

give an example program to keep it redraw every frame in the whole stage area. 
on some low spec pc, run this flash would cost 90% or higher cpu resource

```
package
{
    import flash.display.BlendMode;
    import flash.display.GradientType;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;

    [SWF(width="1200", height="600", frameRate="24")]
    public class Test5 extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test5()
        {

            var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
            g.beginFill(0x4000);
            g.drawRect(0,0,1200,600);
            g.endFill();
            var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sp.alpha = 0.5;
            sp.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
            sp.cacheAsBitmap = false;
            this.addChild(sp);
            g = sp.graphics;
            var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.createGradientBox(1200,600,0,0,0);
            var count:int = 0;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function(e:Event):void{
                g.clear();
                g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL,[0xff,0],[1,0.3],[count++%256,255],matrix);
                g.drawRect(0,0,1200,600);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

if shrink the window's size ,the cost will come down significantly.if enlarge it to 1920x1080,the fps will go down.

same thing happened for Bitmap too,like moving a stage size cloud picture from one side to another side.

my question is why does view size cost so much?since the stagewidth and stageheight didn't change,so i suppose the flash player only scale the final result and bitblt.but maybe i was wrong, can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to render a lot more if you scale up the window?

Rendering graphics is probably the most processor intensive thing that Flash does, so increasing the amount of content it needs to draw onto the screen is going to hurt performance.

Comment: but the content are the same ,right?if the player always draw the original size and scale it,i don't think the cost would get so much difference

Comment: @user2003548 You're misunderstanding how rendering works. Just consider for simplicity's sake that if it's *larger* then there's *more* to draw. It might be the same object, but the process of selecting which pixels on the screen need to be recolored is the issue.

Comment: alright, i might write a similar application someday,maybe i will understanding the rendering mechanism behind this.